# AG Grid headerComponentFramework prop is not rendering custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, custom-headers

I am attempting to create a custom header using AG Grid and React, but am unable to render the custom component that is passed into the `headerComponentFramework` prop within my `autoGroupColumnDefs`.

The [AG Grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-header/#example-custom-header-component) points to using `headerComponentFramework`, and when editing their example code with their Plunker link I am successfully able to create and edit a custom header. When I attempt to implement the same thing in my code, I'm not able to even access my component. E.g. I tried to console.log a message from my custom header component, but it didn't log. I also tried alternate props, such as `headerComponent` and `headerGroupComponent` but those didn't work either.

Sample code below:

```
import CustomHeaderComponent from './filePath';

autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo(() => {
  headerComponentFramework: CustomHeaderComponent
  headerName: ‘name’,
  suppressMenu: true,
  cellRendererSelector: () => {}
  pinned: left,
}), [dependencies])

gridOptions = { 
  …otherGridOptions,
  autoGroupColumnDefs
}

return (
  <AgGridComponent 
    gridOptions={gridOptions}
  />
)
```

```
export const CustomHeaderComponent = {
  console.log(‘hello world’); // doesn't log

  // do stuff 

  return (
    <div> {Custom Header} </div>
  )
}
```

Is `headerComponentFramework` the correct prop to use here? If anyone has suggestions on how to render a custom header, it would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide additional details as well.

Comment: please could you provide a stackblitz or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in using `headerComponent` and registering my component in the `frameworkComponents` prop:

```
autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo(() => {
  headerComponent: 'customHeaderComponent'
  headerName: ‘name’,
  suppressMenu: true,
  cellRendererSelector: () => {}
  pinned: left,
}), [dependencies])

gridOptions = {
  …otherGridOptions,
  frameworkComponents: {
    customerHeaderComponent: CustomHeaderComponent
  },
  autoGroupColumnDefs
}
```

I'm still not sure why `headerComponentFramework` isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had AG version 26.2.0 using with React 18 - instead of giving out any errors, it just skips rendering the header component and render nothing in the column headers: see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6vka95?file=src%2FApp.jsx) for a reproduction.

Upgrade to AG version 27+ fixes it.